# how to fix these errors in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

[image]

I tried static-content:deploy -f
and cleared cache .But no use

Comment: Try removed generated files and again run bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f. $ rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/* generated/*

Comment: try with setup:upgrade -> setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f -> c:f

Comment: I tried everything, but not worked

Comment: Ensure that folder owner/permissions are proper before running command. Check below link. https://support.weltpixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001868933-How-to-set-Magento-2-permissions-and-avoid-installation-errors

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run this command (if you're in production mode):

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB
bin/magento c:c && bin/magento c:f
```

and you should be good

Answer (score 0):

Run Below command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB --theme Sm/market
```